# List all folders from directory and push into array

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to make a script that recursive read all folders and insert it to multidimensional array.

So I create an example path to test this script. My folder:

TesteFolder

```
-1
 -11
 -12
 -13
```

My expect output in json:

```
  { 
    "name": "1",
    "pathTo": "TestFolder/1",
    "children": [{
        "name": "11",
        "pathTo": "TestFolder/11",
       }, 
      {
        "name": "12",
        "pathTo": "TestFolder/12",
        }, 
       {
        "name": "13",
        "pathTo": "TestFolder/13",
       }
    ]
}
```

I tried:

```
$folders = array();

function listFolder($dir,$folders){
   $prov = array();
   $ffs = scandir($dir);
   foreach($ffs as $ff){
      if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
          $prov[] = $ff;
          if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {  
              $folders['children'] = listFolder($dir.'/'.$ff,$prov);  
          }
      }    
   }
   return $folders;
}

$arr = listFolder('TesteJSON',$folders);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: A bit of sensible code indentation goes a long way to making your code a) readable and b) **Debuggable**

Comment: Also, your "intended output" fails a JSON syntax check. What do you REALLY want as your output?  Is "11" a subdirectory of "1" which is a subdirectory of "TesteFolder"? For clarity, could you show us the output of `find . -type d -print`, and make sure your JSON is at least valid, if not formatted for readability?

Comment: There is a }] extra, I will edit. Yes "11" is a subdirectory of "1" whick is a subdirectory of "TesteFolder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion is messed up a bit. You can simply return the array in each recursion, something like this.

```
function listFolder($dir) {
   $result = array();
   $ffs = scandir($dir);
   foreach($ffs as $ff){
      if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
          $info = array("name" => $ff, "pathTo" => $dir.'/'.$ff);
          if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {  
              $info['children'] = listFolder($dir.'/'.$ff);  
          }
          $result[] = $info;
      }    
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Note that the code is not tested, and only ment to demonstrate a simple "return value" recursion. Also note that probably symbolic links to folders may cause circular references, which can result an infinite recursion, but this is only a guess as I'm not currently deep in PHP environment.

Comment: It does get the children but If I have more folders, It will not work well, there will be just one parent folder for all the folders and subfolders. Try to debug it with more folders in the directory

Comment: @TiagoCastro I can't see any error at first glance which could cause the behavior you wrote. Unfortunately I don't have the environment now to debug it. Please if you manage to find the error, and it is in the code sample, leave a comment.

Comment: Instead of foreach try this one :    foreach($ffs as $ff){
      if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
          $info = array("name" => $ff, "pathTo" => $dir.'/'.$ff);
          if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {  
              $info['children'] = listFolder($dir.'/'.$ff);  
          }
          if (empty($info['children'])){
            unset($info['children']);
          }
          $result[] = $info;
      }    
   }

Comment: @Dolfa, that shouldn't matter I think overall. I prefer to keep a consistent object structure, so every folder item will have a `children` property, regardless whether it's empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:

```
 $folders = array();

function listFolder($dir,$folders){
   $prov = array();
   $ffs = scandir($dir);
   $provv = array();

   if (empty($folders)){//parent folder
      $folders['name'] = $dir;
      $folders['pathTo'] = $dir;
   }
   foreach($ffs as $ff){
      if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
          $prov['name'] = $ff;
          $prov['pathTo'] = $dir.'/'.$ff;
          $provv[] = $prov;
          if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
              $folders['children'] = listFolder($dir.'/'.$ff,$provv);  
          }
      }  
   }
   return $folders;
}

$arr = listFolder('test',$folders);
echo json_encode($arr);
```